# Event-Driven Programming in Python: Changing color & size of the turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

My task is to draw a traffic light with turtle. Everytime I hit the space the turtle moves with different colors and traffic light changes. I have successfully completed this task. But there are some extra tasks i couldn't accomplish.

1) Changing color of the turtle with R, G, and B. For example: the turtle is in the green light (bottom) position. But i want to change it to red by pressing R.

2) I want to change my pensize of my turtle with + and -.

This is my code that works. I just couldn't write additional lines that will fulfill the two tasks.

```
import turtle           # Tess becomes a traffic light.

turtle.setup(400,500)
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Tess becomes a traffic light!")
wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")
tess = turtle.Turtle()


def draw_housing():
    """ Draw a nice housing to hold the traffic lights """
    tess.pensize(3)
    tess.color("black", "darkgrey")
    tess.begin_fill()
    tess.forward(80)
    tess.left(90)
    tess.forward(200)
    tess.circle(40, 180)
    tess.forward(200)
    tess.left(90)
    tess.end_fill()


draw_housing()

tess.penup()
# Position tess onto the place where the green light should be
tess.forward(40)
tess.left(90)
tess.forward(50)
# Turn tess into a big green circle
tess.shape("circle")
tess.shapesize(3)
tess.fillcolor("green")

# A traffic light is a kind of state machine with three states,
# Green, Orange, Red.  We number these states  0, 1, 2
# When the machine changes state, we change tess' position and
# her fillcolor.

# This variable holds the current state of the machine
state_num = 0





def advance_state_machine():
    global state_num



    if state_num == 0:       # Transition from state 0 to state 1
        tess.forward(70)
        tess.fillcolor("orange")
        state_num = 1
    elif state_num == 1:     # Transition from state 1 to state 2
        tess.forward(70)
        tess.fillcolor("red")
        state_num = 2
    else:                    # Transition from state 2 to state 0
        tess.back(140)
        tess.fillcolor("green")
        state_num = 0

# Bind the event handler to the space key.
wn.onkey(advance_state_machine, "space")

wn.listen()                      # Listen for events
wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import turtle           # Tess becomes a traffic light.

turtle.setup(400,500)
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Tess becomes a traffic light!")
wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")
tess = turtle.Turtle()


def draw_housing():
    """ Draw a nice housing to hold the traffic lights """
    tess.pensize(3)
    tess.color("black", "darkgrey")
    tess.begin_fill()
    tess.forward(80)
    tess.left(90)
    tess.forward(200)
    tess.circle(40, 180)
    tess.forward(200)
    tess.left(90)
    tess.end_fill()


draw_housing()

tess.penup()
# Position tess onto the place where the green light should be
tess.forward(40)
tess.left(90)
tess.forward(50)
# Turn tess into a big green circle
tess.shape("circle")
tess.shapesize(3)
tess.fillcolor("green")

# A traffic light is a kind of state machine with three states,
# Green, Orange, Red.  We number these states  0, 1, 2
# When the machine changes state, we change tess' position and
# her fillcolor.

# This variable holds the current state of the machine
state_num = 0





def advance_state_machine():
    global state_num



    if state_num == 0:       # Transition from state 0 to state 1
        tess.forward(70)
        tess.fillcolor("orange")
        state_num = 1
    elif state_num == 1:     # Transition from state 1 to state 2
        tess.forward(70)
        tess.fillcolor("red")
        state_num = 2
    else:                    # Transition from state 2 to state 0
        tess.back(140)
        tess.fillcolor("green")
        state_num = 0
def blue():tess.fillcolor('blue')
def red():tess.fillcolor('red')
def green():tess.fillcolor('green')
def bigger():tess.shapesize(tess.shapesize()[0]+1)
def smaller():
    try:tess.shapesize(tess.shapesize()[0]-1) # try so that it wont return exception if the size is 1. size cant be less than 1
    except:pass
# Bind the event handler to the space key.
wn.onkey(advance_state_machine, "space")
wn.onkey(red, "r")     # press "r" key to change the color to red
wn.onkey(green, "g")   # press "g" key to change the color to green
wn.onkey(blue, "b")    # press "b" key to change the color to blue
wn.onkey(bigger, "+")  # press "+" key to increase the circle size
wn.onkey(smaller, "s") # press "s" key to decrease the circle size. i tried minus key but didnt work.


wn.listen()                      # Listen for events
#wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: I turns out that '-' (and '+') have special meaning when it comes to Tk key binding so try `wn.onkey(smaller, "minus")` (and `wn.onkey(bigger, "plus")`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your requirements differently than @avalanche -- my solution follows.  It all still hinges on adding more key events (like your space bar event) just as @avalanche showed so +1 for him:

```
""" Tess becomes a traffic light. """

from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def draw_housing():
    """ Draw a nice housing to hold the traffic lights """
    tess.pensize(3)
    tess.color('black', 'darkgrey')

    tess.begin_fill()
    tess.forward(80)
    tess.left(90)
    tess.forward(200)
    tess.circle(40, 180)
    tess.forward(200)
    tess.end_fill()

wn = Screen()
wn.setup(400, 500)
wn.title("Tess becomes a traffic light!")
wn.bgcolor('lightgreen')

tess = Turtle()

draw_housing()

# Position tess onto the place where the green light should be
tess.penup()
tess.left(90)
tess.forward(40)
tess.left(90)
tess.forward(50)

# Turn tess into a green circle
tess.shape('circle')
tess.shapesize(3)
tess.fillcolor('green')

# A traffic light is a kind of state machine with three states,
# Green, Amber, Red.  We number these states  0, 1, 2
# When the machine changes state, we change tess' position and
# her fillcolor.

SLOW, STOP, GO = range(3)

# Y position, color, next state; 'orange' filling in for 'amber'
STATE_MACHINE = { \
    SLOW: (120, 'orange', STOP), \
    STOP: (190, 'red', GO), \
    GO: (50, 'green', SLOW) \
}

# This variable holds the current state of the machine
state_num = SLOW

def advance_state_machine():
    global state_num

    position, color, next_state = STATE_MACHINE[state_num]

    tess.sety(position)
    tess.fillcolor(color)
    state_num = next_state

def bigger():
    stretch_wid, stretch_len, outline = tess.shapesize()
    tess.shapesize(stretch_wid, stretch_len, outline + 1)

def smaller():
    stretch_wid, stretch_len, outline = tess.shapesize()
    if outline > 0:
        tess.shapesize(stretch_wid, stretch_len, outline - 1)

def stop():
    global state_num
    state_num = STOP
    advance_state_machine()

def slow():
    global state_num
    state_num = SLOW
    advance_state_machine()

def go():
    global state_num
    state_num = GO
    advance_state_machine()

# Bind the event handlers
wn.onkey(advance_state_machine, 'space')
wn.onkey(stop, 'r')  # press 'r' key to change the light to red
wn.onkey(slow, 'y')  # press 'y' key to change the light to yellow
wn.onkey(go, 'g')  # press 'g' key to change the light to green
wn.onkey(bigger, 'plus')  # press '+' key to increase the circle size
wn.onkey(smaller, 'minus')  # press '-' key to decrease the circle size.

wn.listen()  # Listen for events

wn.mainloop()
```

One difference is the 'r', 'y' and 'g' keys advance the light to that color state rather than just change the current cursor color.  And the '+' and '-' keys change the pen outline size, not the cursor size.

Plus I reworked your state machine logic and other details.